# What is the error in the following reasoning regarding the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: logic, set-theory, riemann-hypothesis

I encountered the following earlier today and was wondering where, or if there are, errors in the reasoning.

Assume the Riemann Hypothesis is independent of ZFC.

Assert that the RH is false, though due to its assumed independence, it is unprovably false.

If the RH is false, a non-trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ exists that is not located on the critical line.

However, the existence of such a point could be used as proof of the falsehood, which would contradict the assumption that RH is independent and false. Therefore, the Riemann Hypothesis is either independent and true, or decidable.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the non-trivial zero not located on the critical line would have to be verifiably so in order for the reasoning to hold. In other words, assuming RH is independent and false, let $p$ be a zero of $\zeta(s)$ not located on the critical line. If the proposition $\zeta(p)$ is decidable, then the above reasoning should hold.

The reason I speculate on this condition is because similar reasoning could be applied to well-known undecidable propositions such as the Continuum Hypothesis:

Assume the Continuum Hypothesis is independent of ZFC.

Assert that the CH is false.

If the CH is false, there exists a set $S$ such that $\aleph_0 < |S| < c$.

The existence of such a set can be used as proof of the falsehood of the CH. Therefore, the CH is either independent and true or decidable.

I'm guessing I am wrong on several points here, and I would greatly appreciate any clarification/explanation/thoughts.

Comment: for CH the slippery assertion is "there exists a set" as the notion of set existence is tricky; for RH the reasoning is well known as there are arithmetic inequalities equivalent to it, so if RH is false is theoretically checkable so by finding a number that violates said inequality which must exist then;  see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008177

Comment: @Conrad Thanks! Shouldn't "there exists a set" be involved in any "there exists" statement, as all objects are sets?

Comment: again the notion of set is slippery (remember the paradox of the set that doesn't contain itself) so not sure what the statement that all objects are sets means; for RH we deal with numbers, and its falsity is equivalent to the fact that a very simple algorithm stops

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Russell's Antinomy is avoided by the axiom of regularity.

Comment: I am not well versed in set theory but I know that the notion of set existence is tricky (eg large cardinals) unless you can actually define the set concretely and anyway that is beside the point regarding RH as there are concrete statements that involve just natural numbers and computable numbers related to them equivalent to it so one can check on a computer some inequality for n; if it fails then RH is false so as noted one just writes an algorithm and let it run and if it stops then RH is false;

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help! Am I correct in concluding that since RH can be described by a relatively simple statement, for example, $\exists x(Re(x)\neq \frac{1}{2} \wedge \zeta(x)=0)$, can be made simple with explicit $x$, therefore if it is true and RH is independent then RH is true, assuming usual arithmetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You raise two different questions, with rather different associated issues.

With regard to the Riemann Hypothesis, the decidability question is essentially the same as with many other currently undecided statements, e.g., "there are no odd perfect numbers". If there is such a number, then one can verify it with a computation, and the computation can be carried out "inside" ZF--indeed, inside Peano Arithmetic (PA). As pointed out in the comments, and as you correctly guessed,  RH has the same character: if it's false, it's "computably false".

This feature of PA is known as $\Sigma_1$ completeness. Any statement that can be expressed in the form $\exists x\;\psi(x)$, where $\psi$ is a so-called recursive (or computable) predicate, is, if true for the "standard natural numbers", provable from PA.

Not all number-theory assertions take this form. For example, consider "there are infinitely many prime pairs". If true, then there is an $N$ with no prime pairs larger than $N$. But how would you computably know that that was true about $N$? The statement takes the form
$$\exists N\;\forall p\!\!>\!\!N\; \psi(p)$$
where $\psi(p)$ is computable. The $\exists\forall$ prefix makes this not $\Sigma_1$.

CH is like this, only worse. Its negation can be expressed in the form
$$\exists S\subseteq\mathbb{R}\;\forall f\; \psi(f)$$
where $\psi(f)$ says, "$f$ is neither a bijection between $S$ and $\mathbb{R}$, nor between $S$ and $\mathbb{N}$".

So again we have the $\exists\forall$ prefix. But this time, $\psi(f)$ doesn't look particularly "computable".

Comment: Would a "proof" by incompleteness be possible? *i.e.* given some proposition such that its negation can be expressed as a $\Sigma_1$ sentence, if the proposition is provably undecidable can we infer that it is true? (or something along those lines)

Comment: $\Sigma_1$ completeness of PA says that if a $\Sigma_1$ sentence of PA is true (in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$), then PA proves it. Contrapositively, if a $\Sigma_1$ sentence of PA is unprovable in PA, then it's false. (The negation of a $\Sigma_1$ sentence is called a $\Pi_1$ sentence.) Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: For ZF, things are much hairier. There is a notion of a $\Sigma_1$ sentence of ZF (analogous to $\Sigma_1$ for PA), but with infinite objects, it's not clear how to represent them. Since there are only countably many descriptions, but uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, some particular subset of $\mathbb{N}$ might be a counterexample to some statement, and yet there might not be any way to describe the subset.

Comment: Ah, got it. My thought was that if you have a proposition $\mathcal{P}$ in PA with $\neg \mathcal{P}$ expressable as a $\Sigma_1$ sentence, with $\mathcal{P}$ being undecidable in PA. Then, assert that $\mathcal{P}$ is false. This implies that $\neg \mathcal{P}$ is true and provable, which it can't be since $\mathcal{P}$ is undecidable on PA, thus there can be no proof in PA of $\neg \mathcal{P}$. Therefore, $\mathcal{P}$ is true.

Comment: That's right. $\Sigma_1$ completeness for PA says that "true $\Rightarrow$ provable" for $\Sigma_1$ sentences; contrapostively, "unprovable $\Rightarrow$ false", or talking about the negations, for $\Pi_1$ sentences (like your $P$), "un-disprovable $\Rightarrow$ true".

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: But just to reiterate, ZF is not $\Sigma_1$ complete, so this reasoning doesn't work for set theory (except in very special cases).

Comment: Right. Do you have an example of a special case?

Comment: These results from the theory of computation do not help with any real-world problem.  Even if there is a finite computation verifying a $\Sigma_1$ claim - it could be bigger than the size of the universe - so you'd never find it.  On the other side - even if a $\Pi_1$ claim has a finite proof - the shortest proof may be bigger than the size of the universe so you'd never find it.  Fermat's Last Theorem is $\Pi_1$ like RH and these computability considerations didn't help.

Comment: Continued: There are theorems like the 4-color theorem that were reduced to a large finite problem solved by computer - but the beef is the mathetical proof that reduced them to a tractable computable problem - and the reduction is itself a tractable-length mathematical proof.

Comment: @JohnDoe what about the case described above, where there is a $\Pi_1$ claim that is undecidable on PA? You can show that the claim cannot be false, therefore it is true by LEM.

Comment: @SebastianCorry: As far as I know such statements are all Godel-incompleteness type self-referencing statements, not "real-world problems".  It is all inside the realm of logic.  The proofs of independence of CH/GCH from ZFC or AC from ZF are much bigger achievements and have substance beyond self-reference.

Answer (score 1):

Provably false means that a statement is false in all models of $\mathsf {ZFC}$.

Let's use a simpler example.  The statement $\exists x~(x^2+1=0)$ is undecidable in the theory of fields with characteristic $0$.  That just means there are some models of the theory (such as $\Bbb C$) that contain a solution (typically known as $i$) and other models of the theory (such as $\Bbb R$) that contain no solution.

That's what's going on here.  For the continuum hypothesis, there are some models that contain a set with cardinality strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, but that set doesn't exist in all models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.  Similarly, if the Riemann Hypothesis is undecidable, it means that there's an off-critical-line solution of $\zeta(s)=0$ in some models but that particular $s$ isn't present in all models.

Comment: the falsity of RH being equivalent to the termination of a simple algorithm, it won't depend on any model that contains the usual arithmetic; not sure there is anyone in mainstream math that cares about any model that doesn't contain the usual arithmetic

Comment: Alright, thanks! I assume this is what stops independence/undecidability from being a proof tactic. Just out of curiosity, what distinguishes two different models of ZFC? Do they differ in axioms? If so, why are they different models and not different systems?

Comment: @Conrad Could you elaborate on what you mean by the falsity of RH being equivalent to the termination of a simple algorithm?

Comment: read the paper of Lagarias I mentioned above for details and see this MO post for more details - especially the answer of Emil Jerabek which provides an inequality with computable numbers that is equivalent with RH so just run the inequality negation for n and if it stops RH is false; https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31846/is-the-riemann-hypothesis-equivalent-to-a-pi-1-sentence

Comment: @Conrad: All models of ZFC contain "the usual arithmetic" with a definition of $\mathbb{N}$ and everything provable about natural numbers in ZFC holds.  But the model of $\mathbb{N}$ can be a non-standard model, and "termination" of an algorithmn means it takes an integral number of steps - with the integer possibly being non-standard.  It is not possible to distinguish internally within the model whether its $\mathbb{N}$ is non-standard.  The non-standardness is external in the meta-theory.

Comment: @SebastianCorry Different models don't differ in axioms.  Go back to the simple example of my answer.  Both models satisfy all of the axioms of fields with characteristic $0$.